# MONAI Image Segmentation Roadblock

Tags: python, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, pytorch, image-segmentation

I am (trying) using MONAI's unetr model to create an image segmentation model for CT scans. I have been following along this guide to help me in jupyterhub. Currently, the block of code I am trying to run does not produce an output, and causes my kernel to restart / crash. I don't really understand why. Here's the code for reference:

```
data_dir = "/panfs/jay/groups/25/lab_name/x500/"
split_json = "dataset_0.json"

datasets = data_dir + split_json
datalist = load_decathlon_datalist(datasets, True, "training")
val_files = load_decathlon_datalist(datasets, True, "validation")
train_ds = CacheDataset(
data=datalist,
transform=train_transforms,
cache_num=24,
cache_rate=1.0,
num_workers=8,
)
train_loader = DataLoader(train_ds, batch_size=1, shuffle=True, num_workers=8, pin_memory=True)
val_ds = CacheDataset(data=val_files, transform=val_transforms, cache_num=6, cache_rate=1.0, num_workers=4)
val_loader = DataLoader(val_ds, batch_size=1, shuffle=False, num_workers=4, pin_memory=True)
```

The dataset/JSON that I am loading isn't very large >200 lines, and the format of the JSON should be correct (I just replaced the example data with my own files). I'm not quite sure why the code isn't running.

I've tried various implementations to get some sort of result. For this, I followed along a guide and have troubles here during the data inputting step